# Apache Ignite: unit test fail for java17 and junit5

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit5, ignite

I recently upgraded my project to java17 and springboot 3.1.1, and using gridgain community  8.8.34.

Everything works fine except unit tests. When I tried to test creating cache, at the line of code:

```
 QueryEntity queryEntity = new QueryEntity(AffinityKey.class, Object.class);
```

the followingexception will be thrown

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.<clinit>(IgniteUtils.java:896)
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity.processAnnotationsInClass(QueryEntity.java:780)
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity.processKeyAndValueClasses(QueryEntity.java:764)
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity.<init>(QueryEntity.java:159)
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.address field is unavailable.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2.run(GridUnsafe.java:1588)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2.run(GridUnsafe.java:1575)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe.bufferAddressOffset(GridUnsafe.java:1575)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe.<clinit>(GridUnsafe.java:114)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field long java.nio.Buffer.address accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.nio" to unnamed module @38082d64
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2.run(GridUnsafe.java:1580)
    ... 96 more
```

I tried to add vm parameters in this unit test run configuration, but not work. Does anyone have the similar issue before?

Comment: How many JDK do you have on your computer?

Comment: jdk11 and jdk17, but env var is pointing to jdk17

Answer (score 0):

When running on Java 17, you need to have a few extra JVM options. See [the documentation](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/getting-started/quick-start/java#running-gridgain-with-java-11-or-later).

```
--add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.math=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.sql/java.sql=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED
```

You can add them on the commandline:

```
mvn test -DargLine="--add-opens...."
```

Or by adding the options to your pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>--add-opens=...</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I added, but still not work

Comment: Which (specific) JDK are you using? When I use Corretto 17.0.8 and "openjdk version "17.0.8.1" 2023-08-24" I get exactly the same error as you _without_ the JVM options and it works when I add them.

Comment: I tried both Corretto 17.0.6 and temurin 17.0.6, but not work. The application can run without any issue if I add those VM parameters, but only the unit tests fail.

Comment: How are you adding the options? I get the same error if I _don't_ supply them but it works if I add them with the `-DargLine` option to the Maven command line or use the Maven Surefire plugin.